# Mypy errors in Generic class

Tags: python, mypy

I slightly modified the [documented mypy generic example](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#defining-generic-classes) but got an error:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[int, float])

class Person(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, salary: T) -> None:
        self.salary: T = salary

    def get_yearly_bonus(self, amount: T) -> None:
        self.salary += amount

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Person(salary={self.salary})"

p = Person[int](9)
p.get_yearly_bonus(6)
print(p)
```

It seems mypy *fails to recognize* the fact that `self.salary` and `amount` *must*
be of the *same* type.

```
$ mypy test.py 
test.py:11: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float", variable has type "T")
test.py:11: error: Unsupported operand types for + (likely involving Union)
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't mypy failing to recognize that `self.salary` and `amount` share a type. mypy knows they both have type `T`, whatever `T` is.

The problem is that `T` isn't guaranteed to be either `int` or `float`. `T` can be any subtype of `Union[int, float]`. It could be `int`, or `float`, or any subclass of those classes, like `bool`, or it could even be `Union[int, float]`!

For a sum of two objects of type `T`, mypy cannot assume the sum has type `T`. The most specific type mypy can deduce for the sum (accounting for mypy's weird special case that treats `int` as a subtype of `float`) is `float`, which isn't assignable to `self.salary`.

If you wanted `T` to be either `int` or `float`, a union bound isn't the way to do that. The syntax for "either `int` or `float`" is

```
T = TypeVar('T', int, float)
```

With `T` specified this way, mypy can type-check `Person` against both possible types and see that the class is valid both ways.

Comment: I though this was the solution as well, but I found that using this syntax, `mypy` correctly identifies a problem when a `float` value is passed to a `int` `Person`, but sees no problem with an `int` being passed to a `float` `Person`. Technically, that wouldn't cause issues as an `int` value can always stand in for a matching `float` value, but I wonder if that's what OP is after, since there would still be a mismatch allowed.

Comment: @Grismar: As I mentioned, mypy has a weird special case that treats `int` as a subtype of `float`, so it thinks `6` and `9` are floats.

Comment: @Grismar this is a special case, and note, it actually *can* cause issues, if you specify `float` and really mean it, because you are using something like `my_float.hex()`

Comment: Ohhh I wasn't aware of that ! Other than the type-relations between `int` and `float`, an important point for me is that `Union[A, B]` is bounded by itself ! so it can be `A` or `B` or `Union[A, B]` - definitely something I didn't think of until now

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree - I think the reasoning for the idiosyncracy is clear, but it doesn't seem wise (and I wonder what case it was supposed to cover, that the authors of `mypy` put it in for)

Comment: @Grismar I think it is an example of "practicality meets purity". The fundamental problem to me seems to be that there is no true numeric tower in Python that would allow you to do something like `Real` if you really did want to cover both cases